# SQL Table Split-Is it necessary

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I've a table with around 6-7lacs records and it's going to grow as time passes.It has around 16-20 columns in it. There are no one-many relationship to any of these columns.

User data entries are stored in these table.

So would it be feasible to split my table into multiple small tables or else just split the table into 2 halfs one with all the entries in it and other the recently fresh records which would be present to the data entry operators to feed in their entries.

In short my question is whether the mysql execution time would be faster if I split the tables, or would it be faster if I split them into two half's.

I guess the latter would be more feasible since it would not perform any join queries.

Updated:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `primary_category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `front_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `back_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_dt_month` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_dt_day` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_dt_yr` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_width` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_height` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dpi` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dpix` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dpiy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_stock` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outlet` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emotional_keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mechanical_keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `notes` text,
  `comments` text,
  `exported_to_ebay_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `exported_to_ebay` set('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `updated_worker_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_worker_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked_worker_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked_worker_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_admin_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_admin_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_manager_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_manager_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager_review` set('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `paid_status` set('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `exported_to_web_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `exported_to_web` set('Y','N') DEFAULT 'N',
  `prefix` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_premium` set('Y','N') DEFAULT 'N',
  `template` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'HIPE_default',
  `photographer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `copyright` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `step` set('1','2') DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `part` (`part`),
  KEY `primary_category_id` (`primary_category_id`),
  KEY `updated_worker_id` (`updated_worker_id`),
  KEY `updated_worker_dt` (`updated_worker_dt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1013687 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The above is my table structure.After there are entries being made say around 1lac I would split it into another table say images_history with same structure.Is this feasible or should I split them into multiple tables to reduce the query execution time

Comment: Can you add some DDL describing roughly what your table looks like and what it would look like if it were split?

Comment: thanks for editing ... didn't know why it wasn't formatting

Comment: For those of you unfamiliar with asian numbers, 1 lakh = 100'000

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to split the table? It would lead to a ton of extra code and slow down the execution time by adding extra queries if you still want to access both of the new tables. (If one of the tables are going to store rarely used previous versions of records of the images table - i.e. version control - it may still be a good idea).

Before even thinking about splitting the table, see if you can increase performance by optimizing the existing code by making sure none of the following performance disasters are:

- Do all SELECTs filter by PRIMARY KEY?
- Is the index cache large enough to hold all indices in the computers RAM?
- Are any string matching SELECTs with LIKE using the indices? I.e. only exact matches or wildcards on the right, never on the left (e.g. "searchword%" and never "%searchword"
- Are there any slow performing queries that use SELECT * instead of selecting only the columns you need?
- Have you avoided using OR in SELECTs?

Performing queries on a table with 700 000 records shouldn't be slow if tabels are properly indexed and queries are actually using those indices.

Comment: Yes by indexing the performance would boost up, but what if I divide the tables which has around 15-20 column in it --- to 3-4 tables each having 5-6 columns and having a good indexing. Does doing this would reduce my sql execution time? that's my real question

Comment: if you have a column that is of a BLOB kind (TEXT, LONGTEXT), a SELECT * or SELECT blobcolumn will force the data to be written to a TMP table on disk instead of RAM. Having a lot of columns will AFAIK not slow down anything if you actually access the columns you actually are going to use by using indexed columns.

Comment: @ Harald: Thanks! I don't have many text columns only 2-3( check my structure above  ).So would the query execution time increase If I ran a query such as Select * and as I have only indexes on few columns only.Is splitting of tables a necessity then?